# duplicate. or not. a case study

Tags: support, specific-question, exact-duplicates

First I want to clarify that I don't want to complain. 
I am very happy because I found an answer after some research. [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70991/the-son-of-a-cohen-who-married-the-daughter-of-a-non-jewish-father) 
 
But I see that the question has been called "duplicate" to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65954/marriage-of-a-cohen-to-a-woman-with-a-non-jewish-father-are-the-sons-cohanim)
 but the later is unanswered. 
I worked a little for the answer. is it lost? Perhaps we need to migrate the answer? Meanwhile I pasted the answer in the two.
I have full confidence that in moderators decisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not lost. Answers on duplicate questions can be migrated by a mod to the 'main' question (it's called a question merger). If you see a case where a merge is appropriate, feel free to flag it for moderator attention and explain what you want done. In this case you've already posted your answer to both so I think we'll just leave it for now.

Also note that duplicate questions don't generally get deleted as they are seen as useful signposts to help other people find the information. (If one person couldn't find the original and had to ask again, so will someone else.)

You can read more about duplicates in [the M.SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/166155).